# Finding out the nodes from spherical symmetric equation for mathematica and then plotting it in gnu-plot

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, graphing-functions, mathematica, spherical-coordinates

What I want to do is to draw a curve for the  spherical partial differential equation for S at rho=0:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2S}{\partial \rho^2}+\frac{d-1}{\rho}\,\frac{\partial S}{\partial \rho}
-S+S^3=0
\end{equation}

I have drawn by mathematica by applying the code:

```
    Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[
   S[r] /. (NDSolve[{S''[r] + 1/r S'[r] - S[r] + S[r]^3 == 0, 
         S[1/1000] == #, S'[1/1000] == 0}, S, {r, 1/100, 15}] & /@ 
      Range[ic - wi, ic + wi, wi/2])], {r, 1/100, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {-2.5, 5}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
  ImageSize -> 800], {{ic, 3.5, "bundle start"}, -7, 
  7}, {{wi, 1.5, "bundle width"}, .5, 2}]
```

the code give the graph like:
[image]

But the graph will be according to the article:
[image]

The professor mailed me to do in this way but I'm bit confuse what exactly he says.

The professor suggests me this

**The nodes of a curve are where its values cross zero. So the values of rho where S=0 in this case. At the mathematica file you should plot only one curve. When the central value, S at rho=0, is slightly below 2.2062 for 2+1 dimensions, then going outwards the curve approaches zero, but then diverges to plus infinity. If you are slightly below that value, it diverges to minus infinity. Fine tuning, i.e. shooting, between this two behavior there is one solution where the value tends to zero at infinity.
If you do the same around the central value 3.3319, then you get a solution which crosses the S=0 line before it tends to zero, and then blows up at the positive or negative direction. The limiting solution has one node at around rho=3.7 and tends to zero at infinity.**

After he said to use gnuplot.

So how do I get the the Fig with different nodes and the  value of TABLE:1 (in the paper) with  the Figure (3) and (4)

> I have tried to get node for single curve by using the mathematica
>   code but the central values given in the [TABLE:1 page no 8  (below the page)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525) aren't resembling with mine. I'm I doing
>   wrong to get the nodes?

[image]

Source: [article page no:7, Fig: no 1,2](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525)

Comment: I am not entirely clear on what you are asking.  Are you essentially asking about how the data from TABLE 1 of the linked paper was obtained?  (And also how to apply this method to situations described in FIGs 3 and 4?)

Comment: yup, you are right. I have done what I have posted by mathematica, but the author says that he did it by gnu-plot with some additional works (I have added his mail).

Comment: man how many sites are you going to shop this around to? Did you change the plot range like suggested yesterday?

Comment: @george, sorry. Some one from this platform told me to post this question to mathematica because he thought this question was belong to Mathematica but when I post this question there, they thought this was a analytic question. So I deleted there and re-posted here. **If admin in this group think this is a irrelevent question then I must delete this.**

Comment: after looking at the paper, i'd say this is a numerical problem that is beyond the capability of simply directly plugging in to mathematica's NDSolve. You'd proably get more help if you worked harder at explaining it more clearly.

Comment: I have written what I did and also the mail from the professor. Actually I tried to fix the problem and trying to match the value with the papers but I failed each time. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The boundary conditions are important.  Your code has (approximate) conditions on $S'(0)$ and you vary the value at $S(0)$  You have to find some way to enforce that $S\rightarrow 0$ as $\rho\rightarrow\infty$.  Your professor is giving you one way to do that.  He is suggesting that you search for the right values of $S(0)$ and $S'(0)$ that give you solutions that decay at infinity.  The authors of the paper searched through the right values and tabulated some of them for $S(0)$ to 8 digits of precision.  They don't give you their results, however, for $S'(0)$.

It is an optimization problem, but it's basically "trial and error" done in a systematic way.  The authors of the paper have done that for you for this equation.  They found the stable (that don't blow up) solutions to the differential equation, and tell you that there are a family of stable solutions, each of higher and higher oscillatory order.  They call this oscillation number as the number of "nodes".

If you insist on verifying the results of that paper, you'll have to write your own optimization routine that find the right $S'(0)$ and $S(0)$ values that cause $S\rightarrow 0$ as $\rho\rightarrow 0$.  You'll get the numbers in the paper if you do this.  I'm sorry I can't be more specific, because this is a non-trivial coding task.  But it can be done.

**Edit**

The below gives you one plot from the paper.  I won't be editing this post any further about gnuplot, or how to extend this to $D=3$, or how to FIND the initial conditions that satisfy the "vanish at infinity" boundary condition.  I described how you do that above, it is simply a systematic trial and error, just as your professor described.  Best of luck.

```
S0 = S[r] /. 
   NDSolve[{S''[r] + 1/r S'[r] - S[r] + S[r]^3 == 0, 
     S[1/10000000000000000] == 2.20620086, 
     S'[1/10000000000000000] == 1}, S, {r, 1/1000, 15}];
S1 = S[r] /. 
   NDSolve[{S''[r] + 1/r S'[r] - S[r] + S[r]^3 == 0, 
     S[1/10000000000000000] == 3.33198927, 
     S'[1/10000000000000000] == 0}, S, {r, 1/1000, 15}];
S2 = S[r] /. 
   NDSolve[{S''[r] + 1/r S'[r] - S[r] + S[r]^3 == 0, 
     S[1/10000000000000000] == 4.15009404, 
     S'[1/10000000000000000] == 0}, S, {r, 1/1000, 15}];
S3 = S[r] /. 
   NDSolve[{S''[r] + 1/r S'[r] - S[r] + S[r]^3 == 0, 
     S[1/10000000000000000] == 4.82960282, 
     S'[1/10000000000000000] == 0}, S, {r, 1/1000, 15}];
Plot[{S0, S1, S2, S3}, {r, 1/100, 14}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Comment: I have tried to match  $ S \rightarrow 0$ if $\rho \rightarrow 0$ but didn't get appropriate. would you mind coding only one central value then I will be able to follow your pattern. Thanx in advance.

Comment: I have answered several of your questions pertaining to using Mathematica to recreate results from papers about oscillons.  I mean no offense, but I suggest you take some extra courses in differential equations and numerical analysis if you continue to work on this research topic.  Stackexchange can't do your research for you.

Comment: Thank you I hope I can Do the rest of the works basis on your works.